# Non-commuting projection operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples, mathematical-physics

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space. Can you provide an example of 3 orthogonal projection operators which are mutually non-commuting?

Comment: Hint: If $PQ = QP$, then what can you say about the subspaces $P(H)$ and $Q(H)$?

Comment: If $PQ = QP$, then this map is the projection onto the subspace $P(H) \cap Q(H)$. This scenario makes sense. I have a harder time visualizing what happens if $PQ \ne QP$.

Comment: why do you need three projections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take three distinct unit vectors which are not pairwise orthogonal, and consider the orthogonal projections on the lines they span.

Comment: and the product of two such projections is NOT the intersection of the images!!! (got confused for an hour by the comment of LaGatta)